# Javascript function writing convention

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I encountered this snippet of code, but I'm having trouble reading it, I have never seen code written this way.

```
showMenuButton[isOpened ? "hide" : "show"]();
hideMenuButton[isOpened ? "show" : "hide"]();
isOpened ? container.removeClass("hideMenu") : container.addClass("hideMenu");
```

Is it the same as

```
if(isOpened="hide"){
showMenuButton();
}
else{
hideMenuButton();
}
```

Could someone explain what the code is doing and why they are writing this way? Is it simply because they are shorter? (I have never seen the [ ] in function calling).

Thank you.

Here is the full javascript code.

```
menuToggle = $("#menuToggle"),
        showMenuButton = $(".menuToggle_show"),
        hideMenuButton = $(".menuToggle_hide"),
        toggleSideMenu = function (isOpened) {

        showMenuButton[isOpened ? "hide" : "show"]();
        hideMenuButton[isOpened ? "show" : "hide"]();

        isOpened ? container.removeClass("hideMenu") : container.addClass("hideMenu");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has [2 ways of referring to objects/method calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) - the dot-notation and the square-bracket notation. They are interchangable, and equivalent, so the following 2 lines will be identical

```
var x = someObject.someProperty;
// or 
var x = someObject["someProperty"];
```

This also works for methods, so again the follwoing two both work (note the difference from the above is parentheses which call the method)

```
someObject.someFunction();
// or 
someObject["someFunction"]();
```

Now, relating this back to your question, there is another trick at work; ternary operators:

```
var result = someCondition ? trueResult : falseResult
```

Putting this all together

```
showMenuButton[isOpened ? "hide" : "show"]();
hideMenuButton[isOpened ? "show" : "hide"]();
```

Equates to

```
if(isOpened){
    showMenuButton["hide"](); // or, showMenuButton.hide();
    hideMenuButton["show"](); // or, hideMenuButton.show();
}
else{
    showMenuButton["show"](); // or, showMenuButton.show();
    hideMenuButton["hide"](); // or, hideMenuButton.hide();
}
```

(Its basically toggling a show/hide button depending on whether it's currently in an opened state or not)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for clearing that up. Is there a reason that they are writing this way? Seems the "if statement" is way easier to understand and debug. or Is it simply because it's shorter? Is there any complication to write code this way, deprecation may not be likely, but anything else?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Those are objects storing functions:

```
var functions={
    alertName:function(){
        alert('My name is Angel');
    },
    alertLastName:function(){
        alert('My last name is Cool');
    },
    alertMySite:function(){
        alert('angelcool.net');
    }
}

functions['alertMySite']();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ugav811/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is exactly that, it is calling the functions `hide()` and `show()`, from the jQuery object, the ternary operators do make it more compact, the most friendly code to look, would go like:

```
if( isOpened  ){
   showMenuButton.hide();
   hideMenuButton.show();
   container.removeClass("hideMenu");
}else{
   showMenuButton.show();
   hideMenuButton.hide();
   container.addClass("hideMenu");
}
```